# React Tick timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I just started learning react recently. I want a tick timer to show up on the screen and the time will update every one second.

Now the time shows up when the page is initially loaded, but it is static. There is no error in console. What should I do in my code?

Here is a part of my code:

```
function timer(){
return new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
}
setInterval(timer, 1000);

const element = (
  <div>
  {getGreeting(user)}
  <h1>It is {timer()}.</h1>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

And here is a screenshot of result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svyDd.png)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

The current display time would be a state of your component. Use `setInterval` to update the state to trigger a re-rendering.

Better yet, use `setTimeout` and set the duration to the next second minus the current time.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/3yLneqy7/

```js
class Time extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.timer = 0;
        this.state = {
            time: new Date()
        };
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        // set up timer
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                time: new Date()
            });
            this.componentWillMount();
        }, Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) * 1000 + 1000 - Date.now());
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        // remove timer
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
    
    render() {
        // render the current time
        return this.state.time.toLocaleTimeString();
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <span>
                <span>The time is </span>
                <Time/>.
            </span>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

By seeing how you are doing

```
function timer(){
    return new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
}
setInterval(timer, 1000);
```

I believe you are new to JavaScript. I suggest you to code without using any library or framework (with vanilla Javascript) until you are confident with the basics.

Answer (score -1):

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        timer:""
    }
  }


  componentWillMount(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.setState({
        timer: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
      })
      this.componentWillMount();
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Timer</h1>
        <h1>{this.state.timer}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: While the code might solve this problem, answers usually benefit from an explanation, what the code does and why this addresses the problem. This helps people understanding better the underlying problem solving strategies.